# .class button on click

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a div with multiple like buttons and i  have the following code where when a user press on one of the like buttons it returns the data-catid value.

```
$('.likes').click(function(){
            var catid;
            catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
             $.get('/rmb/like_image/', {like_id: catid}, function(data){
                       $('.likes').html(data);
                       $('.likes').attr('disabled','disabled');
                   });
        });
```

My problem is instead of returning it to the only button that was pressed , its returning the value to all buttons. I know it has something to do with this line

```
$('.likes').html(data);
```

but i am not sure how to fix it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the current clicked element, so use a closure variable to store the reference to the clicked element then use that reference on the ajax callback.

```
$('.likes').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        catid = $this.attr("data-catid");
    $.get('/rmb/like_image/', {
        like_id: catid
    }, function (data) {
        $this.html(data).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please explain more about closure variable or any link.

Answer (score 1):

Just update only the current element.

```
$('.likes').click(function () {
var self = $(this);
    var catid = self.attr("data-catid");
$.get('/rmb/like_image/', {
    like_id: catid
  }, function (data) {
    self.html(data).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.likes').click(function(){
        var catid;
        thatVar = $(this);
        catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");            
        $.get('/rmb/like_image/', {like_id: catid}, function(data){
                   thatVar.html(data);
                   thatVar.attr('disabled','disabled');
               });
    });
```

Could you try if this works?

Comment: that is dangerous as now `that` is a global variable, if some other function also makes a similar mistake and updates the value of that before the response comes back... you will have a problem